# How to automatically call the keypress event (enter key) to navigate to next page?

Tags: sapui5

How to  automatically call the keypress event (enter key) to navigate to next page after we  input in the textbox using SAPUI5? The Data entered in the text box is being automatically populated from a 3rd party application, and on population of data in the text box, it should navigate to next page without explicitly calling keypress event.

Comment: How do you know  the 3rd party app has finished "entering" text?

Answer (score 2):

Register "**change**" or **any other** event, which will be fired once the needed text reached the input.

Inside callback check whether text is valid and if so - navigate to any page by using "navTo" method of router.